# Theory of Coding - Pinter's Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, coding-theory

I have been self-studying Charles Pinter's *A Book of Abstract Algebra* and I have gotten stuck on one of the exercises. I managed to come up with a solution, but it feels a bit incomplete  or maybe missing some details and was hoping to get some feedback on my proof.

Here is the question:

---

**3.G.6**

Let $m$ denote the minimum distance in a code, that is, m is the smallest number of places in a code in which two words differ.

By the *sphere of radius $k$* about a codeword $\textbf{a}$ we mean the set of all words in $\mathbb{B}^n=\{a_1a_2\dots a_n:a_i\in\{0,1\}\}$ whose distance from $\textbf{a}$ is no greater than $k$. This set is denoted by $S_k(\textbf{a})=\{\textbf{x}:d(\textbf{a},\textbf{x})\leq k\}$.

If $t=\frac{1}{2}(m-1)$, prove that any two spheres of radius $t$, say $S_t(\textbf{a})$ and $S_t(\textbf{b})$, have no elements in common. [Hint: Assume there is a word $\textbf{x}$ such that $\textbf{x}\in S_t(\textbf{a})$ and $\textbf{x}\in S_t(\textbf{b})$. Using the definitions of $t$ and $m$, show that this is impossible.]

---

And here is my attempt at a proof. I did some scratch work first in the first two paragraphs, and some of the words I used in proving the triangle inequality may not be rigorous, so if you have suggestions let me know:

If there is a word $\textbf{x}$ in the intersection of the two spheres, then we have both $d(\textbf{a},\textbf{x})\leq \frac{1}{2}(m-1)$ and $d(\textbf{b},\textbf{x})\leq \frac{1}{2}(m-1)$.

Thus if the triangle inequality holds for this $d$, we can deduce that $d(\textbf{a},\textbf{b})\leq m-1$, contradicting the assumption that the minimum distance in the code $C$ is $m$, and the result will follow.

As for the triangle inequality, note that $\textbf{a}$ and $\textbf{b}$ are codewords in a code $C$ with minimum distance $m$. That is, for some $\textbf{a}$ to be transformed into $\textbf{b}$, there must be at least $m$ changes to $\textbf{a}$.

Suppose we can change $\textbf{a}$ into $\textbf{c}$ by only changing $k_1$ places, and $\textbf{c}$ into $\textbf{b}$ by only changing $k_2$ places.

If no position is changed more than once in the transformation

$a\to c\to b$

then clearly we have equality:

$d(a,b)=d(a,c)+d(c,b)$.

Suppose the $i$th position is changed more than once in the transition from $a$ to $c$ to $b$. Then the original value at position $i$ (in a) is the same as the value in position $i$ in b. Suppose this occurs in p positions, say $a_{i_1},\dots,a_{i_p}$. In other words, $a_{i_j}=b_{i_j}$ for $j=1\dots p$.

Thus we can more efficiently go from $a$ to $b$ through a new word $c'$ by changing the other $k_1-p$ places to go from $a$ to $c'$, then the other $k_2-p$ places to go from $c'$ to $b$. Thus finally we have:

$$
d(a,b)=d(a,c')+d(c',b)
=k_1-p+k_2-p < k_1+k_2 = d(a,c)+d(c,b). \square
$$

---

I have a feeling I can write this more elegantly using a group of subsets of a set as explained earlier in the chapter, because there seems to be a relationship between groups of subsets of a set with the symmetric difference as the binary operation and what we are doing here, but I am not quite sure how to phrase it. So any help in this direction would also be appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to prove?

Comment: As you wrote the original thing you want to prove is an obvious corollary if the triangle inequality.  Most people who believe the hamming distance is a metric would leave it at that . It sounds like you are more interested in proving the hamming distance is a metric and satisfies the triangle inequality?

Comment: Essentially yes. I am ultimately interested in proving their claim that the spheres have no intersection, but I see it relies on the triangle inequality of this metric. I've never seen the metric before though and was wondering if my proof of the triangle inequality was correct.